# In jqxGrid click on cell is deleting the saved value

Tags: javascript, grails, jqxgrid

In my `jqxGrid` my columns format is custom.
When I click on cells if there is saved data on that cell grid is deleting it, when i click `Esc` key on my keyboard the value comes back, when i click with mouse on some part of the grid table the value remains deleted.

I have tried to imitate the Esc key on mouse click but it does not worked

```
        var columns =  [
            {
                text: 'Անվանում',
                dataField: 'device_name',
                width: '15%',
                editable: false,
                pinned: true,
                cellsrenderer: customRenderer
            },
            {
                text: 'INDEX',
                dataField: 'ind',
                width: '15%',
                editable: false,
                columntype: 'default',
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                text: '',
                dataField: 'saveRow',
                columntype: 'button',
                align: 'center',
                width: 100,
                cellsalign: 'center',
                pinned: true,
                cellsrenderer: function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties, rowdata) {
                    let device_name = $('#jqxgridDevice').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'device_name');
                    let sub_ind = $('#jqxgridDevice').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'sub_ind');
                    if (device_name != 'ժամ / րոպե' && sub_ind != 0) {
                        return "Պահպանել";
                    } else {
                        return '        ';
                    }
                },


                           'SPN-CPAP (Ինտուբացիոն խողովակ)', 'SPN-CPAP (Տրախեոստոմիկ խողովակ)',  'SPN-CPAP (NIV ոչ ինվազիվ դիմակ)']
                        if (breathingTubes.includes(device_name)) {
                            var selectBox = $('<select name="type" style="width: 56px; heigh: 21px"><option value="">'+ "" +'</option><option value="ԻԽ">'+ "Ինտուբացիոն խողովակ" +'</option><option value="ՏԽ">'+ "Տրախեոստոմիկ խողովակ" +'</option><option value="NIV">'+ "NIV ոչ ինվազիվ դիմակ" +'</option></select>');
                            $(editor).append(selectBox);
                            selectBox.focus()
                            // Handle editor value changes
                            selectBox.on('change', function () {
                                // Update the editor value to synchronize with the input
                                editor.val(selectBox.val());
                            });

                        } else {
                            // Create a jqxInput (textbox) editor
                            var inputElement = $('<input type="number" class="jqx-widget jqx-input jqx-rc-all" style="width: 35px; height: 21px;" />');
                            $(editor).append(inputElement);

                            // Handle editor value changes
                            inputElement.on('input', function () {
                                // Update the editor value to synchronize with the input
                                editor.val(inputElement.val());
                            });
                        }
                        inputEditor = editor.find("input[type='number']");
                        selectEditor = editor.find("select");

                },
```